# Is there a way to ask for another input on the same line?

Tags: python

I need multiple inputs but I don't want there to be more than one line.  In my case, I made a while loop for exceptions in case the user inputs a string instead of an integer.  If the user input an incorrect value, then I want the input line to clear and ask for another input on the same line with an error message two lines below the input just after.

The idea:

```py
while True:

    try:

        value = int(input("> ")) # , end="\r"  something similar to this maybe

        break

    except ValueError:

        print("\n\n[Invalid Input]")  # two lines from the original input line
```

Comment: Inputs are just strings... so split the values and then int each one.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim i cant do that if the input isn't numerical.   i just need a method which allows me to ask the user if an exception occurs with another input on the same line.

Comment: Really you can take them all and then either throw away the non int vals and finish the program, or you will have to use a new input line to get corrections to any of the non int vals.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim ok i understand.  So if an exception occurs, I need to use a new input line?  I can't ask again on the same line?  It would be awesome if I could just incorporate the `end="\r"` method with `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension on the split values will work for this.

`input.split()` will give you a list of inputs.

Then the list comprehension loops through and tries to int each val. If any of them trigger a value error, you are still inside the try-except.

```
value = None

while True:
    try:
        value = [int(x) for x in input('> ').split()]
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("\n\n[Invalid Input]")
```